# Confused about return value in arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I found this code in one a tutorial.

```
const renderApp = (Component) =>
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer>
          <Component />
        </AppContainer>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

My question is shouldnt the return value be wrapped in braces? because arrow functions return whats next to => if nothing is metnioned ?

```
const renderApp = (Component) => (
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer>
          <Component />
        </AppContainer>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
)
```

shouldn't it have braces to wrap contents ?

Comment: The reason it's not wrapped in () is because it's a one-liner :)

Comment: No, you only need round parentheses when you're returning an anonymous object `val => ({ prop: val });`.

Comment: Im still not getting it. The first code snippet, after "=>" its empty, wont JS compiler insert ; and end it there ? why will it return render functions output ? Thanks

Comment: @vikasr78 - *"wont JS compiler insert ; and end it there"* No. It would with a `return` statement, but not with an arrow function's `=>`. They're fundamentally different things.

Comment: You mind find [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/218196) interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The right hand side of an arrow function can be either:

- A block

  - delimited with `{` and `}` (which are braces)
  - which returns whatever the `return` statement in the block says
- An expression

  - which returns whatever the result of evaluating the expression is

You need to wrap the expression with parenthesis (`(` and `)`) if it is an object literal because object literals are delimited with braces.

```
() => { foo: 123, bar: 456 }; // This is an error
```

If you wrote the above, the `{` and `}` would be interpreted as a block and not an expression to create an object.

```
() => ({ foo: 123, bar: 456 });
```

Adding parenthesis tells the JS parser that it is an expression and not a block.

Since your expression doesn't start with a `{`, it won't be treated as a block so there is no need for parenthesis.

---

> The first code snippet, after "=>" its empty, wont JS compiler insert ; and end it there ?

No. Automatic semi-colon insertion only occurs in places which **could** be the end of something. It won't happen in after `=>` because there **must** be something on the right-hand side of `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to wrap it within braces because a single line statement gets returned implicitly. You however can do it yourself, it isn't incorrect, just that it's a bit of syntactic sugar